# How to Bypass Ngrok Browser Warning

Tags: ngrok

I'm pretty new in Ngrok. I always got warning about abuse. It's just annoying, that I wanted to test measure of my site but the endpoint it's get into the browser warning.

How to send an [ngrok-skip-browser-warning] request header to bypass this warning?

[image: Browser Warning]

Comment: What browser are you using? For Chrome, there are plugins that allow you to set headers. I haven't used this one so I can't vouch for it, but it seems like it should do the trick: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

Comment: To add headers from any browser you can use Modify Headers Rule of Requestly.

(Disclaimer: I am associated with the company)

Answer (score 28):

> Set and send an [ngrok-skip-browser-warning] request header with any
> value

This is what you have to do to bypass the browser warning: You have to include the request header `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` with any value in the request header.
The exact syntax of what is to be included depends on the type of the api call you're making.
For instance for a `fetch` request in javascript, this is what has to be included to bypass the warning:

```
fetch(url, {
      method: "get",
      headers: new Headers({
        "ngrok-skip-browser-warning": "69420",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I want to add my URL as webhook in Facebook. But we cann't configure the custom header there. Any other solution?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani if you are able to run ngrok *behind a proxy*, check out my answer. In your case, you need the simplest VM with the static IP, which will proxy the traffic to ngrok.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and this can be solved much easily through the ngrok dashboard only.

> Create a tunnel with a request header having key: ngrok-skip-browser-warning and value:true

1. Go to edges

[image]

2. Add request header and start the tunnel

[image]

3. Start a tunnel
   [image]
4. Finally you can now access the without the warning page
   [image]

Comment: It's also working with "Start a tunnel from the command line". Thanks for the workaround

Comment: Yes that can be done in either of the 3 ways

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR;** For those still curious about how to **automate** a workaround, I've created a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/igops/ngrok-skip-browser-warning) which runs a simple HTTPS proxy locally and adds `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` header to each request.

Run:

```bash
$ docker run -d --rm \
  -p 8443:443 \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -e NGROK_HOST=https://your-ngrok-domain.ngrok.io \
  igops/ngrok-skip-browser-warning:latest
```

From now, use `https://ngrok.localhost.direct:8443` as your API webroot.

E.g., you were told to call `GET https://your-ngrok-domain.ngrok.io/api/v1/whatever`. Now you just call `GET https://ngrok.localhost.direct:8443/api/v1/whatever` instead, and get the response **without the warning page!**

`*.localhost.direct` is a wildcard record of the public DNS pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

[Read more](https://hub.docker.com/r/igops/ngrok-skip-browser-warning)

---

The main idea under the hood is running Nginx with the following config:

```yaml
server {
    server_name localhost ngrok.localhost.direct;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.direct.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.direct.key;

    location / {
        # regular forwarding headers
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host your-ngrok-domain.ngrok.io;

        # this line does the actual trick
        proxy_set_header ngrok-skip-browser-warning 1;

        # forward!
        proxy_pass https://your-ngrok-domain.ngrok.io;
    }
}
```

Feel free to use.

Answer (score 5):

Add following to the header

```
headers.set("ngrok-skip-browser-warning", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to test your app from Chrome you can use the Chrome extension [Requestly](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/requestly-intercept-modif/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en-US) for it.

- Add extension
- Create an rule `ngrok-skip-browser-warning`
- Add Condition 1(Wildcard): `https://*.ngrok-free.app/*`
- Add Condition 2(Wildcard): `https://*.ngrok-free.app`
- Add Request header to both conditions `ngrok-skip-browser-warning`=`true`

*If you need to use it in Incognito: go to Extension settings set allow incognito*
*If you need you can specify Site access in Extension settings eather*

[image]