# How do i edit "ngrok-skip-browser-warning" into the request sheader?

Tags: web, raspberry-pi, apache2, ngrok, request-headers

I am pretty new to ngrok and web dev but I am trying to host a apache2 server on my raspi4 and i wanted to make it public to the outside using Ngrok but whenever anyone goes on the link they are prompted with the browser warning page --[browser warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9VEg.png). I want to remove it by setting `ngrok-skip-browser-warning =1` into the **request header**, yet I don't now where I find that on my apache2 server. How to I edit the request header?

Comment: The request header is from the client, so they would need to set it.

Comment: This question is already answered here. Hope that will help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844702