# ngrok-skip-browser-warning terminal

Tags: python, ngrok

I want to to skip-browser-warning in ngrok

I did not find a solution except to use the ngrok API, and I searched for a way to use it, but I could not find. Can someone write an example or if there is another solution to hide the warning, please help me.

[image: picture of the problem]

Comment: duplicate. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844702/4481226