# Can I bypass ngrok warning page?

Tags: web-applications, proxy, port, ngrok

I wanna show my web application to my client by hosting it online.

I used ngrok, then it always display warning page and it has my ip address.
I hate to show my ip address to client. I think we can use proxy.
I don't know how to use proxy in ngrok.
Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ngrok binary does not reference any strings related to the warning page, meaning that is out of our control. If that wasn't the case there could be a way to reverse engineer it but that's out of question.

The warning page explicitly states the following:

- Set and send an `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` request header with any value.
- Or, set and send a custom/non-standard browser `User-Agent` request header.
- Or, please [upgrade](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/login) to any paid ngrok account.

---

More information here: [How to Bypass Ngrok Browser Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017353/how-to-bypass-ngrok-browser-warning)