# CORS Error when I use django api with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, ngrok, django-cors-headers

I'm using ReactJS on the front end and Django API on the back end. I'm currently testing some functionality by connecting my localhost(backend) to a ngrok URL and hitting that ngrok URL with my ReactJS frontend that is already in its own test environment in PROD.

The POST requests work just fine, but when there is a GET request, in the developer tools in chrome, I get the following:

`Access to fetch at 'https://'{NGROK URL} from origin 'https://{PROD URL}.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I've included the necessary CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS and even CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS.

When I test this from frontend(localhost) to backend(localhost), it works normally.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

PM from ngrok here. This sounds like an issue we've been seeing where the phishing interstitial page we add for free accounts when serving traffic through a browser is getting triggered for some reason.

We just merged a change that should stop the CORS error and at least show you the actual page that's blocking you. To get around the interstitial, follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844702/17282727) and add the `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` to the request to the ngrok url.