# React + Express + Socket.io + Ngrok

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io, ngrok

I have a React app (client-side) and Express (server-side). I am trying to make a connection using Socket.io.

`/client : socket.io-client@4.7.2  /server : socket.io@4.7.2`

```
// server/server.js:

const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const app = express();

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Enable Trust Proxy
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

// Use Helmet middleware to enhance security
app.use(helmet());

// Add this line to parse JSON data in incoming requests
app.use(express.json());

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
cors: {
origin: "http://localhost:3000", // here i am putting the Ngork Client Url "https://ngrok-url.com"
methods: \["GET", "POST"\],
credentials: true,
},
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4821;

io.use((socket, next) =\> {
const clientIP = socket.handshake.address;

Configure JWT authentication middleware
io.use(
socketioJwt.authorize({
secret: secretKey, // my secret from .env file
handshake: true,
})
);
```

```
// client/src/App.js:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './styles.css';

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const token = jwt.sign(
{
username: "myUsername",
},
process.env.REACT_APP_JWT_SECRET
);
const socket = io("http:/localhost:4821", {. // here i am putting the ngork ServerUrl "https://ngrok-url.com"
query: { token },
});

socket.on('connect', () =\> {
console.log('Connected to the server');
});

socket.on('error', (error) =\> {
console.error('WebSocket Error:', error);
});
```

> NGROK Server: (on Virtual machine/Linux Ubuntu/Node.js LTS 18)
>
> 1. sudo ufw status, //(active), sudo ufw allow 4821, sudo ufw reload
> 2. Starting /server - npm start; // script: nodemon node server.js
> 3. Starting ngrok tunnel with - ngrok start server //ngrok.yml http localhost:4821
> 4. Get the Ngrok https SERVER URL
> 5. Paste Ngrok Server URL in /client/App.js // type ctrl+c, npm start again App.js

> NGROK Client: (on MAC)
>
> 1. Starting - /client/src/App.js - npm start
> 2. Starting ngrok tunnel with - ngrok start client //ngrok.yml http localhost:3000
> 3. Get the Ngrok https CLIENT URL
> 4. Paste Ngrok Client URL in /server/server.js // type "rs" in terminal to restart nodemon

When I am using localhost:3000 (client) and localhost:4821 (server) I can see Socket.io connection, I do not have any problems. But when I am using Ngrok I have a big problem, I can not see Socket.io connection.

I do not have errors in the browser console.

In the Network Tab (ALL), when I clicked on /socket... I saw:

`Request URL: https://f65b-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app/socket.io/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhdG9zaGlAMjFubWlsbC5pbyIsImlhdCI6MTY5ODUwNjE1M30.v5hCOKlmMHf3RSEdXTumzO7PEtKzYz-XZrA6CqPsCkg&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OjssoEr Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK (from service worker) Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Content-Length: 1396 Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https://cdn.ngrok.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data: w3.org/svg/2000 Content-Type: text/html Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 15:15:55 GMT Ngrok-Trace-Id: 7ca3e23723940ef090231cf42ad421a1 Referrer-Policy: no-referrer X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Accept: */* Referer: https://ed5e-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app/ Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Brave";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99" Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0 Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"`

In the Network Tab (WS), when I clicked on /socket...  I saw only one sockjs-node, then when I clicked on sockjs-node:

`Request URL: wss://ed5e-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app/sockjs-node Request Method: GET Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols Connection: Upgrade Ngrok-Trace-Id: 58a6ffcdbd0cd5a1ef2d633378c24398 Sec-Websocket-Accept: ONgwe/ms0WvXB6Tb2eIyPvx6dVo= Upgrade: websocket Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: Upgrade Cookie: abuse_interstitial=ed5e-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app Host: ed5e-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app Origin: https://ed5e-185-213-154-249.ngrok-free.app Pragma: no-cache Sec-Gpc: 1 Sec-Websocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits Sec-Websocket-Key: QQjVTB/9a2Ou5OcaPX2YnA== Sec-Websocket-Version: 13 Upgrade: websocket User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\`

What I think is wrong is the fact that I do not have SSL certs for Ngrok (Let's Encrypt). I also think that I need to add two extra lines in the client/src/App.js file, but I am not sure if I really need to:

```
// /client/src/App.js 

...  

const socket = io("http:/localhost:4821", 
{   query: { token },   
withCredentials: true, // NEW LINE   
transport: [websockets, polling], // NEW LINE 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Bypass Ngrok Browser Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73017353/how-to-bypass-ngrok-browser-warning)

Answer (score 0):

I am using now Local Tunnel and I do not have any problems.

```
# Install
npm install -g localtunnel

# Run
lt --port 8000

# Custom subdomain
lt -p 8000 -s mylocaltunnel
```

Thanks me later.

Regards,
mrbpp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

PM from ngrok here. It sounds like you might be hitting an issue with the abuse interstitial that ngrok adds to free accounts as a way to reduce phishing attempts. To get around the interstitial, [follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844702/17282727) and add the `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` header to the request to the ngrok url in `App.js`.

Comment: I cannot understand exactly what to do. Can you help me with the code? 

Kind Regards

Comment: I think my problems came from SSL cert and private key, but i do not know how to get the SSL from Ngrok Dashboard or terminal to paste them in server.js and to read them with '.fs' library, or how can i upload to Ngrok my own cert and key that i will generate from openssl or certbot.